# defining shortest pairs in a list of complex numbers with ValueError: A 2-dimensional array must be passed

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

I need your help.
I hava to calculate distances between points to define shortest pairs, to realize it I've used scipy.spatial.distance.pdist (my points in contour are complex, z=x+1j*y)

```
last_points = np.array([contour.last_point_on_contour() for contour in reached])
print last_points
last_points_2d=np.array([last_points.real, last_points.imag])
dm = pdist(last_points_2d, 'euclidean')
```

and take follow error

```
ValueError: A 2-dimensional array must be passed.
```

Last points are(coordinates of points)

```
[-501.54525930+9.54332241j -496.00082683+7.88953715j
 -494.40471685+2.72497522j -492.63174757-1.58916156j
 -494.39724167-6.69815202j -499.57661541-9.11793037j]
```

I will appreciate for any help. thanks

Comment: In your new version, you're creating an array named `one_point_2d`, but you're passing something else called `last_points_2d`.

Comment: Now that you've fixed that, `print last_points_2d`. Or just `print last_points_2d.shape`. It's going to be 2x6. So, you can't possibly be getting the error you're showing from the code you're now showing.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
one_point_2d=np.array([last_points.real, last_points.imag])
```

last_points is in fact a single point (whatever was last in the for loop).  You want it to include all the points.

Comment: I want include all the points, each point have coordinates(x,y), In this case I have 6 points.

Comment: OK, so go ahead and include them.  Your current code loops to print but not include them.

Comment: @ John Zwinck, as np.array?

Comment: Of course you can't reshape one point to 6x2. You need to put all 6 points into an array, not just ignore the first 5 and use the last one.

Comment: For example: `last_points = np.array([contour.last_point_on_contour() for contour in reached])`. (You can do this by vectorizing instead of using a listcomp, and that's usually cleaner and sometimes faster, but anything but a one-liner in a comment is unreadable.)

Comment: I thought that it will give distance between all points,but it gave me only one.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
for contour in reached:
    last_points = contour.last_point_on_contour()
    print last_points
one_point_2d=np.array([last_points.real, last_points.imag])
```

Just gets each last point, prints it out, and forgets it. In the end, you have only the last one. You need to save all of them.

Here's how to do it with novice-level Python operations:

```
last_points = []
for contour in reached:
    last_point = contour.last_point_on_contour()
    print last_point
    one_point_2d=[last_point.real, last_point.imag]
    last_points.append(one_point_2d)
last_points_2d = np.array(last_points)
```

However, you can do it a lot simpler with either comprehensions, or numpy vectorized operations. For example:

```
last_points = (contour.last_point_on_contour() for contour in reached)
last_points_2d = np.array([[point.real, point.imag] for point in last_points_complex])
```

Or:

```
last_points = np.array([contour.last_point_on_contour() for contour in reached])
last_points_2d = np.array([last_points.real, last_points.imag])
```

Or, if `reached` is an array:

```
@np.vectorize
def last_point_on_countour(contour):
    return contour.last_point_on_contour()

last_points = last_point_on_counter(reached)
last_points_2d = np.array([last_points.real, last_points.imag])
```

Comment: @ abarnert, thank you very much. But I have wrong result(1217.2830045). as you can see in the points, it should be vey small, and I thought it should calculate distance between all of them, because later I have to  order the points. What I did wrong?

Comment: Do you want a 2x6 array, or a 6x2? If you've got the wrong shape, just transpose it by sticking `.T` on the end (e.g., `last_points_2d = np.array([last_points.real, last_points.imag]).T`). Otherwise, you're computing the distance between two 6D points, instead of the distances between six 2D points.